# I have a dictionary of values for 'n' orders. How would I retrieve certain information and store it in an array?

Tags: python

I have a line of code that retrieves orders. Typing output[1] retrieves 'n' amount of orders.

```
output[1] =
[
{'info': 
 {'orderId': 65632,
  'item': 'bananas',
  'qty': '15',
  'clientOrderId': 'grfg_5938fk',
  'price': '0.5083'}
},
 {'info': 
  {'orderId': 25446,
   'item': 'grapes',
   'qty': '6',
   'clientOrderId': 'rrlo_anv345',
   'price': '0.4950'}
 },
 {'info': 
  {'orderId': 69548,
    'item': 'bananas',
    'qty': '9',
    'clientOrderId': 'vueo_t89jdo',
    'price': '0.5063'}
  }]
```

I am looking to create an array to store information from 'item', 'price' and 'qty'. It would look something like this:

```
 array =     
 ['bananas', '0.5083', '15']
 ['grapes', '0.4950', '6']
 ['bananas', '0.5063', '9']
```

How should I do this?

edit: as brought forth by other forum users, the output had missing {} which gave a syntax error. This has now been amended.

Comment: the dictionary you posted is incomplete and what is the type of `output`?

Comment: Hi, that was intentional. I just wanted to focus on one part of the dictionary. So that's why I added the [1]

Comment: How can you access the data from incomplete dictionary it will throw syntax errors

Comment: @MischievousBear That's not a valid dictionary.

Comment: `[{'info': {'orderId': 65632,
   'item': 'bananas',
   'qty': '15',
   'clientOrderId': 'grfg_5938fk',
   'price': '0.5083'}},
 {'info': {'orderId': 25446,
   'item': 'grapes',
   'qty': '6',
   'clientOrderId': 'rrlo_anv345',
   'price': '0.4950'}},
 {'info': {'orderId': 69548,
   'item': 'bananas',
   'qty': '9',
   'clientOrderId': 'vueo_t89jdo',
   'price': '0.5063'}}]` is this what you wanted to post?

Comment: Oops, my mistake! Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dictionary isn't valid, but once it's made valid, that's a way to do it:

```
d = [
    {'info': 
     {'orderId': 65632,
      'item': 'bananas',
      'qty': '15',
      'clientOrderId': 'grfg_5938fk',
      'price': '0.5083'}
    },
     {'info': 
      {'orderId': 25446,
       'item': 'grapes',
       'qty': '6',
       'clientOrderId': 'rrlo_anv345',
       'price': '0.4950'}
     },
     {'info': 
      {'orderId': 69548,
        'item': 'bananas',
        'qty': '9',
        'clientOrderId': 'vueo_t89jdo',
        'price': '0.5063'}
      }]

[ [x['info']['item'], x['info']['price'], x['info']['qty']]  for x in d]
```

result:

```
[['bananas', '0.5083', '15'],
 ['grapes', '0.4950', '6'],
 ['bananas', '0.5063', '9']]
```

Comment: not `map(lambda x:itemgetter('item','price','qty')(itemgetter('info')(x)),d)` ? :P

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I can confirm this method works. :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all there are some missing '}' in the output list.

```
output = [{'info': {'orderId': 65632,
'item': 'bananas',
'qty': '15',
'clientOrderId': 'grfg_5938fk',
'price': '0.5083'}},
{'info': {'orderId': 25446,
'item': 'grapes',
'qty': '6',
'clientOrderId': 'rrlo_anv345',
'price': '0.4950'}},
{'info': {'orderId': 69548,
'item': 'bananas',
'qty': '9',
'clientOrderId': 'vueo_t89jdo',
'price': '0.5063'}}]
```

Use This...

Now for the code:

> ```
> output = [{'info': {'orderId': 65632,
> 'item': 'bananas',
> 'qty': '15',
> 'clientOrderId': 'grfg_5938fk',
> 'price': '0.5083'}},
> {'info': {'orderId': 25446,
> 'item': 'grapes',
> 'qty': '6',
> 'clientOrderId': 'rrlo_anv345',
> 'price': '0.4950'}},
> {'info': {'orderId': 69548,
> 'item': 'bananas',
> 'qty': '9',
> 'clientOrderId': 'vueo_t89jdo',
> 'price': '0.5063'}}]
>
>
> array = []
> for i in range(len(output)):
>     temp = []
>     temp.append(output[i]['info']['item'])
>     temp.append(output[i]['info']['price'])
>     temp.append(output[i]['info']['qty'])
>     array.append(temp)
> print(array)
> ```

OUTPUT :

> [['bananas', '0.5083', '15'], ['grapes', '0.4950', '6'], ['bananas',
>   '0.5063', '9']]

HOPE THIS HELPS